# How to return AND and OR logical operators JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a really long one line if-statement in an ng-if in my html. It got too long so I want to make a function evaluate it instead.

My problem is that I cant get my head around how to "convert" an && or an || to nested if-statements that i could have in an function. Could someone, a bit wiser than me, help me out?

Here is the logic i want to convert to nested if-statements (I indented it to get what I was doing):

```
ng-if="(
  (
    (filter === 'critical') 
    ||
    (
      !(
        (filter === 'status')
        ||
        (filter === 'events')
      )
      &&
      (
        (
          !(door.status_error_array.length >= 1)
          &&
          (door.event_array.length >= 1)
        )
        ||
        (
          !(door.status_error_array.length >= 1)
          &&
          !(door.event_array.length >= 1)
        )
      )
    )
  )
  &&
  (door.critical_error_array.length >= 1)
)"
```

Comment: I dont get what you mean - if you have the logic working, why cant you just move that to a function in your model?

Comment: I don't know how to do that... I didn't think that I could write it just like that? I thought I needed to write it with if statements? Don't I?

Comment: @pandaseal `if(/*current contents*/)`?

Comment: or... `function whatever(filter,door){ return <current content of ng-if>)`

Comment: why do you check `(!(door.status_error_array.length >= 1) && (door.event_array.length >= 1))` twice, connected with OR?

Comment: @NinaScholz they are different.. first time there no ! in front of the second expression, second time it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this logic to a controller. Only very simple expressions should go into the view.

**EDIT**

The first step would be a simple copy-paste, if you are using the $scope rather than controllerAs syntax you will need to prepend `this.$scope` that in the expression otherwise just `this`:

```
YourController.$inject = ['$scope'];
function YourController($scope) {
    this.$scope = $scope;
}

YourController.prototype.testExpresstion = function() {
    return (
  (
    (this.$scope.filter === 'critical') 
||
(
  !(
    (this.$scope.filter === 'status')
    ||
    (this.$scope.filter === 'events')
  )
  &&
  (
    (
      !(this.$scope.door.status_error_array.length >= 1)
      &&
      (this.$scope.door.event_array.length >= 1)
    )
    ||
    (
      !(this.$scope.door.status_error_array.length >= 1)
      &&
      !(this.$scope.door.event_array.length >= 1)
    )
  )
    )
      )
      &&
      (this.$scope.door.critical_error_array.length >= 1)
    )

}
```

Your view would just simply be something like:

```
<div ng-if="testExpression()">
```

Of course don't call it `testExpression`. Give it a contextual name based on what it does.

Once you have that working, write a unit test for this method. Then refactor this method and move each condition into its own method until it becomes clear to any developer what this is supposed to do.

Comment: Yes, that is what I intend to do, as I wrote in the question. The question was: how to "convert" the logic I have in the thml to something i could have in the controller.

Comment: So is that how it works? Same syntax but just with a return in a function? :3 Then I understand that my question sounds very wierd.. I'll try it!